# sort by values for each group in a MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I am trying to convert a MultiIndex dataframe (which was converted from a xarray Dataset with 3 dimensions being time, latitude and longitude and two variables "FFDI" and "REF_ID").

The dataframe looks like:

```
                                    FFDI    REF_ID
latitude    longitude   time        
-39.200001  140.800003  1972-01-20  1.2     0
                        1972-01-21  0.9     0
                        1972-01-22  1.5     0
                        1972-01-23  1.6     0
                        1972-01-24  1.1     0
                        1972-01-25  1.1     0
                        1972-01-26  1.0     0
                        1972-01-27  1.4     0
                        1972-01-28  1.4     0
                        1972-01-29  1.8     0
                        1972-01-30  1.7     0
                        1972-01-31  1.4     0
                        1972-02-01  0.9     0
                        1972-02-02  0.9     0
                        1972-02-03  1.4     0
            ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
-33.900002  150.000000  2020-06-17  0.7     36111
                        2020-06-18  0.9     36111
                        2020-06-19  1.6     36111
                        2020-06-20  1.8     36111
                        2020-06-21  0.6     36111
                        2020-06-22  0.4     36111
                        2020-06-23  0.6     36111
                        2020-06-24  0.6     36111
                        2020-06-25  1.2     36111
                        2020-06-26  1.3     36111
                        2020-06-27  1.1     36111
                        2020-06-28  1.7     36111
                        2020-06-29  0.9     36111
                        2020-06-30  1.8     36111
                        2020-07-01  0.8     36111
                        
639037952 rows × 2 columns
```

The original xarray Dataset three dimensions of time (17696, daily from 1972-01-20 to 2020-06-30) latitude (148) amd longitude (244).

​I would like to sort date/time by FFDI values for each (latitude, longitude) group.

```
                                    FFDI    REF_ID
latitude    longitude   time        
-39.200001  140.800003  2009-02-07  10.2    0
                        2009-01-30  10.1    0
                        1983-02-12  10.0    0
                        2003-01-13  9.8     0
                        2019-12-28  9.8     0
                        2000-01-17  9.7     0
            ...     ...     ...     ...     ...

-33.900002  150.000000  ... ...     ...     ...
                        1994-06-16  0.9     36111
                        1978-07-07  0.2     36111
                        2020-08-28  0.1     36111
                        2007-06-09  0.0     36111
                        1994-07-30  0.0     36111
                        1987-06-21  0.0     36111
                        
639037952 rows × 2 columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both levels and column `FFDI`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['latitude','longitude','FFDI'], ascending=[True, True, False])
```

Or:

```
df = df.sort_values('FFDI', ascending=False).sort_index(level = [0,1], sort_remaining=False)
```

If cannot be sorted by first 2 levels use:

```
f = lambda x: x.sort_values('FFDI', ascending=False)
df = df.groupby(level=[0, 1], group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

df = pd.read_csv("URCSV.csv")
a = ps.sqldf('Select * from df Group by "latitude","longitude" order by "FFDI" ')
print(a)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel tnx for the advice. thought it was clear and easy. just wanted to share my idea as a code.